# Making a chapter header with tikz horizontal rules

Tags: tikz-arrows, fncychap

I'm trying to customize this chapter header by changing the

`\thickhrulefill to \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed}`.

Although the placement of the

`\myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed}`

did not appear as it did with `\thickhrulefill` (I want it with the chapter in the middle with the two rules surounding it as it did in the unmodified one)
Due to the lack of information and experience in this field I'm seeking your help as a beginner.
here is the code of the unmodified chapter header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,openany,twoside]{report}

%%%%%Language

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=57pt}

%%%%%Police

\usepackage{lmodern}% police de caractère
\usepackage{textcomp}% caractères additionnels
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%Graphic

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{footnote}


%%%%%Titling

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%Math

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}%pour psshadowbox
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs

\usepackage{hyperref} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\myrule} [3] []{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[#2-#3, ultra thick, #1] (0,0) to (0.5\linewidth,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Chapter Header

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%
     %\vspace*{10\p@}%
     {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
          \thickhrulefill\quad
           \normalfont\sffamily\scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
           \quad  \thickhrulefill
           \par\nobreak
           \vspace*{7mm}%
           \interlinepenalty\@M
           \hrule
           \vspace*{6mm}%
           \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
           \par
           \vspace*{7mm}%
           \hrule
       \vskip 40\p@
       \vskip 100\p@
     }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%
     %\vspace*{10\p@}%
     {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
           \thickhrulefill
           \par\nobreak
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \interlinepenalty\@M
           \hrule
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
           \par
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \hrule
       \vskip 40\p@
       %\vskip 100\p@
     }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

And here is the code I changed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,openany,twoside]{report}

%%%%%Language

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=57pt}

%%%%%Police
\usepackage{lmodern}% police de caractère
\usepackage{textcomp}% caractères additionnels
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%Graphic

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{footnote}


%%%%%Titling

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%Math

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}%pour psshadowbox
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs

\usepackage{hyperref} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\myrule} [3] []{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[#2-#3, ultra thick, #1] (0,0) to (0.5\linewidth,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Chapter Header

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%

     %\vspace*{10\p@}%

 {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
     \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed}\quad
       \normalfont\sffamily\scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
       \quad  \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed} 
       \par\nobreak
       \vspace*{7mm}%
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \hrule
       \vspace*{6mm}%
       \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
       \par
       \vspace*{7mm}%
       \hrule
   \vskip 40\p@
   \vskip 100\p@
 }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%
     %\vspace*{10\p@}%
     {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
           \thickhrulefill
           \par\nobreak
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \interlinepenalty\@M
           \hrule
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
           \par
           \vspace*{10\p@}%
           \hrule
       \vskip 40\p@
       %\vskip 100\p@
     }}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

- the empty lines in the title definition act as line breaks -> remove
- `center` environment around the tikzpicture will force it on a separate line -> remove
- missing % at line endings are interpreted as spaces -> add
- `.5\linewidth` is to long -> there needs to be space for `\quad chapter 1\quad` -> make shorter
- if you have more than 9 chapters, it might be better to place the number in a box of fixed width

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,openany,twoside]{report}

%%%%%Language

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=57pt}

%%%%%Police
\usepackage{lmodern}% police de caractère
\usepackage{textcomp}% caractères additionnels
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%Graphic

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}% gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{footnote}


%%%%%Titling

\usepackage{titling}% pour le titre
\usepackage{titlesec}% pour les sections
\usepackage{titletoc}% pour la table des matières
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% pour les en-têtes
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%Math

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}%pour psshadowbox
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{calc}% syntaxe naurelle pour les calculs

\usepackage{hyperref} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\myrule}[3][]{%
%    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw[#2-#3, ultra thick, #1] (0,0) to (0.39\linewidth,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
%    \end{center}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Chapter Header

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%
     %\vspace*{10\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
     \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed}\quad
       \normalfont\sffamily\scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
       \quad  \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed} 
       \par\nobreak
       \vspace*{7mm}%
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \hrule
       \vspace*{6mm}%
       \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
       \par
       \vspace*{7mm}%
       \hrule
   \vskip 40\p@
   \vskip 100\p@
 }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to can increase the length of  \myrule[line width = 2mm]{fast cap reversed}{fast cap reversed} ?

Comment: @hanaachan If you want both lines, two \quad and Chapitre 1 in the same line, then no, there is no space to increase the length

Comment: the chapter header looks great but the  table of content needs to match the same style of my rule ... so i went and did the same but the length of it dont look good.(i'll put the code above)

Comment: @hanaachan better make a new question